# Is there anyway to hover over a link, and make that change an image or background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hover

I think the best way to do this would be css or javascript. Also im not even really sure it is possible.

all the css i have

```
html {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/6oqXuwz.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}


/* unvisited link */
a:link {

}

/* visited link */
a:visited {

}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {

}

/* selected link */
a:active {

}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML or CSS? It seems what you want could be easily done with JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: There is no *other* way than JavaScript or CSS. :) But your question is very vague, on par with "can doctors cure me if I am ill?" You will want to provide more detail, hopefully a snippet of relevant HTML/CSS and the precise description of what you wanted to happen.

Comment: it might help: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover

Comment: i have it all very basic in css right now with a background img linked to the body css class and the four basic link/hover/visted/active classes as well. what other code do you need? thanks again!

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
jQuery('#link').hover(function() 
{ 
jQuery('body').css("background-image", "url('foo/bar.png')");
}); 
</script>
```

You could try the above, where # being the ID you can change to a . to use a class. You can also use this to change elements of a div by changing body to again #foo or .foo depending on whether you're using a class or ID. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, he means the background of the entire page

Comment: Thanks I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    $('html').css('background',
    'url(http://i.imgur.com/PsYD2yN.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed')
});
```